# Swift Prepare(for: segue) not called

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

In my storyboard controller1 has natigationController and segues to controller 2. It is weird that the Segue works ok but

> override func prepare(for: segue)

the whole method was not called (I set breakpoint). I reviewed a lot of old questions on stackoverflow, but no one could solve my problem. Thanks!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueId, sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == self.segueId {
        let destionationNVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        guard let targetVC = destionationNVC.topViewController as? ViewController2 else { return }

        targetVC.text = self.text
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call `performSegue` on`self` rather than on the enclosing navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks, but the app crashes at self.performSegue.

Comment: @TonyOakman You need to remove the segue currently connected to the navigation controller, and connect a new one from _your VC_.

Comment: Check the connection of the segue. It must start on the view controller

Comment: @vadian Thanks for your time, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `performSegue` on `self.navigationController`, so it's the `navigationController.prepareForSegue` that will be called, not the one in your VC. You should reconnect the segue to *your VC* in the storyboard, give it the identifier, and call:

```
self.performSegue(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add the segue from the VC's view from the beginning but didn't work. It seems can only add segue from the top left viewcontroller icon.